# Calling a D function directly from C++

Tags: c++, interop, d

I've gone through http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html and in all of the examples, even those where some C++ code calls some D code, the main function resides in D (and so the binary being called is the one compiled from the D source file). The "calling D from C++" example in the doc has a function foo defined in D, which gets called from a function bar in C++, and bar in turn gets called from the main function in D.

Is it possible to just call D code from the C++ function? I'm trying to do something simple like the following, but keep getting build errors:

In D:

```
import std.stdio;

extern (C++) void CallFromCPlusPlusTest() {
  writeln("You can call me from C++");
}
```

Then in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CallFromCPlusPlusTest();

int main() {
  cout << "hello world"<<"\n";
  CallFromCPlusPlusTest();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible, (your mileage may vary depending on the C++ compiler used.)

Firstly, you will have to initialized the D runtime, either from the C++ or the D side.

cpptestd.d:

```
import std.stdio;

extern (C++) void CallFromCPlusPlusTest() {
  /*
   * Druntime could also be initialized from the D function:
  import core.runtime;
  Runtime.initialize();
  */
  writeln("You can call me from C++");
  //Runtime.terminate(); // and terminated
}
```

Compile with:
dmd -c cpptestd.d

cpptest.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CallFromCPlusPlusTest();
extern "C" int rt_init();
extern "C" int rt_term();

int main() {
  cout << "hello world"<<"\n";
  rt_init(); // initialize druntime from C++
  CallFromCPlusPlusTest();
  rt_term(); // terminate druntime from C++
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and link with:
g++ cpptest.cpp cpptestd.o -L/path/to/phobos/ -lphobos2 -pthread

This works for me on Linux.

Comment: Do you have an example that can show passing of strings? So, your D function would receive a string, tack on "-response" on the end, return that value back? Then, the main in the C would printf("RESULT=%s",CallFromCPlusPlusTest("request"); and see RESULT=request-response.

Comment: I took your example and expanded it greatly so that it passes a string to D and then receives it back with "-response" on the end. I then explain how to load this all in XCode so that it compiles D and then even links it into an Objective C Cocoa project: http://forum.dlang.org/post/wihgbphoqytqqlxnefcb@forum.dlang.org