# How to call D functions from Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, d

How could it be possible to call [D functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)) from Objective C? Is such a bridge even possible?

Comment: http://www.dsource.org/projects/dstep/wiki/ObjcBridge/BridgeInternals/ObjcToD

Answer (score 1):

D has limited Objective-C support already: https://dlang.org/spec/objc_interface.html

This thread explains how to do the same from C++: [Calling a D function directly from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923976/calling-a-d-function-directly-from-c)

I guess it should not be difficult to do the same from Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

Since Objective-C still has all the C stuff, they could call each others functions through the `extern(C)` interface too, reducing the problem to the solved issue of calling D functions from C.